# Dynamic Search Page using wildcards

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I have a requirement to be able to search in the Case standard object in fields such as Subject (text 255) and Description (long text area 32000) using wildcards. I found Jeff Douglas codes(http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/13/building-a-dynamic-search-page-in-visualforce/) for a Dynamic Search Page but they work only with a perfect match when using in the AccountName, Subject and CaseNumber fields and I got an error message in the Description field.
I have also found codes for implementing wildcards but I do not know how to integrate the latest in the first ones.

**Visualforce page**

```
    <apex:page controller="CaseSearchController" sidebar="false">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />
  <apex:pageBlock title="Case Search" mode="edit">
  <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>  
    <td width="200" valign="top">
      <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function doSearch() {
        searchServer(
          document.getElementById("accountName").value,
          document.getElementById("Subject").value,
          document.getElementById("Description").value,
          document.getElementById("caseNumber").value          
                    );
      }
      </script> 
      <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
          <apex:param name="accountName" value="" />
          <apex:param name="Subject" value="" />
          <apex:param name="Description" value="" />
          <apex:param name="caseNumber" value="" />
      </apex:actionFunction>
      <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Account Name<br/>
        <input type="text" id="accountName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Subject<br/>
        <input type="text" id="Subject" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
     <tr>
     <td style="font-weight:bold;">Description<br/>
        <input type="text" id="Description" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Case Number<br/>
          <input type="text" id="caseNumber" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
       </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
      </apex:pageBlock>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="results">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="case">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Account Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                          <apex:param name="sortField" value="accountName" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!case.account.name}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Subject" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="Subject" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!case.Subject}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Description" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="Description" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!case.Description}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Case Number" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="caseNumber" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
               <apex:commandLink value="{!case.caseNumber}" action="/{!case.Id}" target="_blank" />
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class - Custom Controller**

```
public with sharing class CaseSearchController {
// the soql without the order and limit
  private String soql {get;set;}
   // the collection of contacts to display
  public List<Case> cases {get;set;}
  // the current sort direction. defaults to asc
  public String sortDir {
    get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;  }
    set;
  }
  // the current field to sort by. defaults to Subject
  public String sortField {
    get  { if (sortField == null) {sortField = 'Subject'; } return sortField;  }
    set;
  }
  // format the soql for display on the visualforce page
  public String debugSoql {
    get { return soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 25'; }
    set;
  }
  // init the controller and display some sample data when the page loads
  public CaseSearchController() {
       soql = 'select id, account.name, subject, description, CaseNumber from Case where account.name != null';
    runQuery();
  }
  // toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
  public void toggleSort() {
    // simply toggle the direction
    sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    // run the query again
    runQuery();
  }
  // runs the actual query
  public void runQuery() {
    try {
      cases = Database.query(soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' limit 25');
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Ooops!'));
    }
  }
  // runs the search with parameters passed via Javascript
  public PageReference runSearch() {
    String accountName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountName');
    String Subject = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Subject');
    String Description = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Description');    
    String caseNumber = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseNumber');
    soql = 'select id, account.name, subject, description, CaseNumber from Case where account.name != null';
    if (!accountName.equals(''))
      soql += ' and account.name LIKE\''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountName)+'%\'';  
    if (!Subject.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Subject LIKE\''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(Subject)+'%\'';
    if (!Description.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Description LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(Description)+'%\'';
    if (!CaseNumber.equals(''))
      soql += ' and CaseNumber LIKE\''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(CaseNumber)+'%\'';  
    // run the query again
    runQuery();
    return null;
  }
   }
```

**Wildcard coding**

```
Visualforce

<apex:page controller="wildcardController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock >
        <apex:inputtext value="{!inputtext}"/>
        <apex:commandbutton value=" Search " action="{!searchRecords}"/>
    </apex:pageblock>
    <apex:pageblock rendered="{!flagshow}">
      <apex:pageblocktable value="{!accList}" var="acc">
        <apex:column value="{!acc.name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!acc.accountnumber}"/>
      </apex:pageblocktable>
    </apex:pageblock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

Controller

Public class wildcardController {
    Public string inputtext{get;set;}
    Public List<account> accList{get;set;}

    Public boolean flagshow{get;set;}
    Public wildcardController(){
     flagshow = false;
    }    
    Public void searchRecords(){
     flagshow = true;
      accList = database.Query('select name,accountnumber from account where name like '+'\''+'%'+inputtext+'%'+'\'');
    }
}
```

Comment: Long text fields can't be filtered using SOQL, Consider using SOSL